# Error Parsing json string sent from js to Java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am tring to send a json string from js to servlet.
I use ajax jquery to post to the servlet.

I can see the servlet post getting called but an exception occurs when I retrieve the json string in java, what am I missing

**Javascript side:**

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(SomeString);

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: fullpath,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonText 
  });
```

Java side:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.json.JSONException;
import com.json.JSONObject;
import com.json.JSONArray;
```

**In post**

```
    response.setContentType("application/json");    
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("jsonText"));//Null pointer exception
```

**Error:**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:33)
        at com.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:84)
        at com.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:314)
```

JSON string:

```
{ "CustomerDetails": [{'name':'Amy','age':'23'},{'name':'Amj','age':'25'},{'name':'Amg','age':'27'}]}
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what Java code are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON being posted?

Comment: You get null pointer at response.setContentType("application/json"); OR JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("jsonText"));

Comment: sorry at request.get parameter

Comment: When posting JSON, there would not be a parameter named jsonText.  Just because that is what the JSON body is called in javascript, does not mean that there is a parameter named that, unless you specifically created a query string with that as one of the keys.

Comment: try with getParameter("data") jsonText is no key, it's value

Comment: sorry i misunderstand jQuery AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `POST`, there is no `jsonText` parameter.  You're just posting the JSON string as the post body.

Try to send it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: fullpath,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {jsonText: jsonText}
});
```

Comment: With this request.getParameter("jsonText") should work right, let me try

Comment: shouldn't it be      data: {'jsonText': jsonText}?

Comment: Yes, now your Java code should work.  Also, you don't need to quote the keys in a JavaScript object.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: if you can't alter what the client sends, you can get the POST data by reading it out as a String from [`request.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) and then passing that String into the `JSONObject` constructor.  However, Rocket's solution is much simpler, as long as you can alter the client behavior.

Comment: @apsillers: Yes, that works too.  I usually don't read from the raw post body unless I have to. :-P

Answer (score 0):

This suggests there is no POST parameter called jsonText

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.